# If $R$ is transitive relation, is $RoR$ also transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

It is true that equivalence relations are closed under composition with themselves, i.e., if $R$ is an equivalence relation $RoR$ is also so because $RoR =R$

But this does not imply that any transitive relation is also closed under composition with themselves. I wonder if this is the case or not, i.e, if $R$ is transitive, is $RoR$ transitive too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is transitive iff $R\circ R\subseteq R$.

If that is the case
then: $$\left(R\circ R\right)\circ\left(R\circ R\right)\subseteq R\circ R$$ so $R\circ R$ is indeed transitive.

Comment: Just Brilliant.

Comment: @LeilaHatami Yes, that's what you asked, but that's not what "closed under composition" means. Normally, when we say that a class $K$ of relations is closed under composition, we mean that if $R\in K$ and $S\in K,$ then $R\circ S\in K.$ In that sense, neither the class of equivalence relations nor the class of transitive relations is closed under composition, because it is easy to find two (different!) equivalence relations $R$ and $S$ such that $R\circ S$ is not transitive.